# Close multipage Phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I am developing a multipage Phonegap app and I need help with navigator.app.exitApp().

I found many solutions for one page applications, but none for multipage. If I try to add a link to cordova.js on each page, the application fails. If I don't add it, the application does not recognize navigator.app

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I use multipage architecture have no problem exiting the app (at whatever page I am) using this:

```
e.preventDefault();
navigator.app.exitApp();
```